# JQuery / AJAX / ASP MVC 3 - Animate a PartialView OnSuccess

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to be able to do some fancy animation using the OnSuccess callback of the Ajax.ActionLink:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink(Html.Action("GetOpenEnquiriesNum", new { id = item.ACCOUNTNUM }).ToString(), "GetOpenEnquiries", new { id = item.ACCOUNTNUM }, new AjaxOptions()
                                            {
                                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                UpdateTargetId = "daybook-result-" + item.ACCOUNTNUM + "",
                                                OnSuccess = "LoadAjaxSuccess"
                                            })
}
```

As you can see, my UpdateTargetId will be different depending on the item.ACCOUNTNUM of my model, so I can exactly do something like:

```
$("#daybook-result-123").slideDown("slow");
```

as the 123 part will be different for every item within my model. So is there anyway I can pass the caller as a parameter to the LoadAjaxSuccess function? Then do something like:

```
function LoadAjaxSuccess(mycaller)
{
$(mycaller).slideDown("slow");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OnSuccess = "(function() { LoadAjaxSuccess(" + Json.Encode(item.ACCOUNTNUM) + "); })()"
```

and then:

```
function LoadAjaxSuccess(id) {
    $('#daybook-result-' + id).slideDown('slow');
}
```

Comment: This sort of works, it doesnt perform the slideDown, but I did .css({"background-color" : "red"}); to test and it did change the bg color to red.

Comment: Ok this is strange, its working now. Thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
OnSuccess = string.Format("LoadAjaxSuccess('{0}')",
                          "#daybook-result-" + item.ACCOUNTNUM)
```